# Can you change/upgrade seats on an American Airlines flight purchased with a travel voucher?

Tags: american-airlines, vouchers

I received a $300 voucher from American Airlines. When I tried to use it to book a flight, the option on the payment page to use a gift card/e-voucher simply didn’t appear. At first we thought it might not let me purchase with a voucher for international travel. But after some trial and error, I realized it was because I had upgraded my seats to Economy Plus.

I booked the flight without upgrading, and the option to use a gift card/e-voucher suddenly appeared. I booked the trip, thinking I could upgrade later. But when I viewed my trip, it wouldn’t let me view, change or upgrade my seats.

I understand the theory on not letting people use vouchers to upgrade seats: they want to incentivize you to book more travel. But I don’t understand why you can’t pay out of pocket to upgrade after the travel has already been booked. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Did you try calling the airline?

Comment: You can always pay for better seats. Call them.

Comment: VTC: as OP has not contacted the airline as suggested in comment, or returned since posting, what is the question, and surely only the airline can remedy the issue.